# azure-ad-b2c Successful verification of otp message

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In Azure-ad-b2c I want users to see that the otp has been successfully verified. However, in ad-b2c window there is no such message appearing and I am not able to find a way to populate a custom message like 'OPT verified'.
All I could see is a metadata in case of incorrect OTP i.e. Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual". Is there something similar for a success case. Below is the default screen I can see in case of successful otp verification.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What about automatically moving to the next page? Other option would be to use some JS to insert a message. There is no option to display a success message, only the Continue button becomes enabled.

Comment: Thanks. I will work with that :)